# Can we use NodeJS for TCP streaming data like we have suppport in Spark Streaming?

Tags: node.js, sockets, apache-spark, tcp, streaming

I want to create a Node JS TCP listener/ client which will continuously keep on reading/ listening data which will be written on a TCP server.

Use case: using IOC, I will get sensor related data on the TCP server, which I want to read ***continuously*** using Node JS.

Is it possible to create a Node JS application which will suffice my above use case? If no please suggest how to accomplish it on a better way? If possible please suggest me how to do it.

Tagging spark, as currently we are thinking to use spark streaming to read TCP server in continuous fashion, but as data is not that huge I am thinking if any better way to achieve this task.

Comment: Have you looked at [Socketio](http://socket.io/)? It might be something to consider.

Comment: yaa I was checking out that, but will that continuously listen to TCP server?

Comment: But have you tried it - you can keep socket connections open and read data like `conn.on('some-event', function (some-data-object){})` - the problem though is that your question will most probably solicit opinions and this is why these should be avoided. Pick one possible solution, try it out and when you encounter error, post those here with specific questions.

Comment: yaa I agree, but as of now we are in deciding which technology to use.

Comment: The worry is that somehow your question has to be marked as "answered" once you find an answer that satisfied you which might be difficult given its opinion-based, Yes-No, nature.

Comment: socket.io is overkill for this, unless you're streaming data to the browser. node has TCP capabilities in the built-in [`net`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html) module.

Comment: @mscdex I have to push data to UI as well. Also in nodejs does it have capability to continuously read TCP

Comment: Yes, with the built-in `net` module as I stated.

Comment: what is your question @vipulpatel I don't understand the context?

Comment: I also have same scenario. I am in development phase with Nodejs net library. So I just want to know is there any problem faced by you. And also want to know which type of server should I use for this type of application. Where my 100 device sending data in every 1 minutes.

Comment: You can create a server in NodeJs follow this https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp also your question is broad as you are asking review of a NodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with using of raw socket: you must synchronize sending data to port; check manually that socket is connected; divide incoming raw-data by package. Below simple client example with `|` as package separator.

```
// Bad code; wait of improvements
'use strict'
const net = require('net');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const util = require('util');

function Listener (opts) {
    this.send = send; 
    let listener = this;

    let queue = [];
    let isBusy = true;
    let socket;

    connect(opts);

    function send (data) {
        queue.push(data);

        if (isBusy)
            return;

        isBusy = true;
        next();
    }

    function next() {
        if (queue.length == 0) 
            return (isBusy = false);

        if (socket) {
            socket.write(data + '|', function (err) {
                if (err)
                    return socket.emit('error', err);
                queue.shift(); 
                next();
            });
        }   
    }

    function connect (opts) {
        socket = net.connect({host: opts.host, port: opts.port});
        queue = [];
        isBusy = true;

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            isBusy = false; 
            listener.emit('connect');
        });

        let buffer = '';
        socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
            buffer += chunk;
            let msgs = buffer.split('|');
            buffer = msgs.pop();

            msgs.forEach((msg) => listener.emit('message', msg));
        }); 

        socket.on('close', () => listener.emit('disconect'));
        socket.on('error', (err) => listener.emit('error', err));       
    }   
}
util.inherits(Listener, EventEmitter);

let listener = new Listener({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 111});
listener.on('connect', () => ...);
listener.on('disconnect', () => ...);
listener.on('error', (err) => ...);
listener.on('message', (msg) => ...);
listener.send('Hello world'); // between connect and disconnect;
```